# HDMI - Sound not working while ingame

Tags: hdmi

I connected my laptop Acer TravelMate 7530 to the LG LCD TV via HDMI cable. I updated all my drivers on the laptop and seemed to work fine. Sound is working fine while I'm not playing games.

But when I go into game, the sound is coming from laptop speakers and not from the TV anymore. Any help?

Comment: Which game(s)? Minesweeper? World of Warcraft?

Comment: Resident Evil 5, Anno 1401 etc..